# table row not matching width of table headings

Tags: html, css

I have a table here: [Table](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/Text3.php)

As you can see the table row is longer than the table headings. I have got a fixed table headings using one table and just including `th` tags and then I create a second table for `td` tags an combine together.

My question is how do I get the table heading to be the same width as the table row and then be able to clip the scroll bar on the side next to the table row?

Below is html:

```
<table id="qandatbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 1205px;">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="2%"></th>
<th class="qid" width="5%">Num</th>
<th class="question" width="13%">Question</th>
<th class="optandans" width="16%">Option and Answer</th>
<th class="noofreplies" width="7%">Number of Replies</th>
<th class="weight" width="6%">Number of Marks</th>
<th class="image" width="17%">Image</th>
<th class="video" width="17%">Video</th>
<th class="audio" width="17%">Audio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
<div id="qandatbl_onthefly_container" style="width: 1221px;">
<table id="qandatbl_onthefly" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr class="optionAndAnswer" align="center">
<td class="plusrow" width="2%">1</td>
<td class="qid" width="5%">2</td>
<td class="question" width="13%">3</td>
<td class="extratd" width="16%">4</td>
<td class="noofreplies" width="7%">5</td>
<td class="weight" width="6%">6</td>
<td class="image" width="17%">7</td>
<td class="video" width="17%">8</td>
<td class="audio" width="17%">9</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Below is CSS:

```
#qandatbl_onthefly_container
{
    width:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:500px;
}

#qandatbl_onthefly
{
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
}

#qandatbl, #qandatbl_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
}       

#qandatbl{
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    clear:both;
}

#qandatbl td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#qandatbl th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
#qandatbl_onthefly_container
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    max-height:500px;
}

#qandatbl_onthefly
{
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
}

#qandatbl, #qandatbl_onthefly{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
    margin-left:0;
    clear:both;
}       



#qandatbl td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#qandatbl th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}


#qandatbl_onthefly td{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

OUTPUT AT MOMENT:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use th to design the heading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in 2 diferrent tables.

Headers are in:

```
table id="qandatbl" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="width: 1205px;"
```

Body is in:

```
table id="qandatbl_onthefly" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center"
```

If you really want to have two different tables you have to make th and td the same width in CSS. I would suggest to make thead and tbody to that what your two tables are currently.

```
thead id="qandatbl"
tbody id="qandatbl_onthefly"
```

(OT: And can somebody please tell me how to format HTML tags at SO ?)

Comment: I have updated the demo which you can see but problem is that the table row is still wider than the table headings, updated css in question

Comment: here the table renders fine. In fact the table rows is 1px smaller than the headers.

Comment: Let me show you screenshot on what it looks like on my screen

Comment: Sory i forgot to change the style in html to change width to make it same. It works, thanks :)